# Auto calculate three weeks ahead in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to put a date in a cell and the cell next to it will automatically pull that date and add three weeks to it?

Example in picture below:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

D2:

```
=C2+21
```

Format as number> date, If necessary.